# Avoid so much escaping in substitution expression

Tags: regular-expression, substitute, escape

I have a substitute expression to find words beginning with a dollar signs and capture them like this:

```
:%s/\$\(.*\)\>//g
```

However there are a lot of escape sequences in the regular expression (4). Is there a way to avoid so many escapes in this expression?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Why even bother capturing in this case? This can be simplified by `:%s/$\k\+//g`. 29% shorter!

Comment: @PeterRincker The word after the $ is being captured. The use of the capture is not shown.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a "very magic" expression:

```
:%s/\v\$(.*)>//g
```

(See `:help \v`)

I'd also note that your expression doesn't do what you say you want it to do. For example, it includes the "bar" in this match: "$foo bar".

Maybe try this instead:

```
:%s/\v\$(\S+)//g
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought that the > symbol was supposed to stop the match at a word boundary. I tried using S+ and it failed to match the word.

Comment: It does. Just not the word boundary you're expecting. For that, you need either to use a non-greedy match, or something easier to type, such as what I or @PeterRincker suggest. My suggestions works correctly for me. Are you sure you typed exactly what I wrote?

Comment: @TylerDurden, `.*` is greedy by default. This means it will capture everything up to a word boundary. So capturing all the words on a line until it finds a word boundary. Use `.\{-}` instead for an un-greedy variant. Or use something like `\k*`/`\w*` to avoid the `\>` in the first place

Comment: I tried :%s/\v\$(\k+) and it does not match

Comment: Please give us some example text so we can help you better. Also `\k` is based off of `'iskeyword'` which can change depending on your `'filetype'`. So `\w` maybe better here

Answer (score 2):

You can use `'magic'` or `\zs` to reduce the need for escaping:

```
:%s/$\zs.*\>//g
:%s/$\zs\k*//g
:%s/\v\$(\k*)//g
```

I am using `\k` to capture anything that looks like a keyword as that will more than likely be what you want and will remove the need for `\>`. With `\zs` your capture group is now `\0`/`&`. The `$` often does not need to be escaped.

Note: `:%s/$\zs.*\>//g` may be too greedy if you want to capture just `$foo`. It will instead capture `$foo bar`. This maybe desired.

For more help see:

```
:h /\zs
:h /\v
:h 'magic'
```